# How to access a configuration object throughout the entire application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a simple Node.js application, throughout which I use static route paths. So I need to know how to access an object without requesting in every route in my application.

Current method =>

**routeLink.js**

```
var routesMap = [{
  createUserRoute: '/create-user',
  route2: '/user-profile',
  // ...
}];
```

**createUserRoute.js**

```
var routLinks = require('./config/routeLink');

module.exports = function(router){
  router.post('/', function(req, res){
     // do the task 
     res.redirect(routLinks.createUserRoute);
  });    
}
```

Just like you see in this example, I have to

```
require('./config/routeLink')
```

without using this how to I access `routesMap` from all of the Routers?

Comment: You can't access files that you don't load. `require()` is one way of loading a file. There are other ways, but you still have to load it at some point. What is your issue with calling `require()` for the files that your application requires?

Comment: maybe require it in app.js(main file) and a way to access without requiring in each and every Routes?...some kind of thing like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two option if you don't want to require your config in each route file:

1/ make your config [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) in your whole application ( not recommended )

2/ use environment variables, take a look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: my question was , can i access routesMap without require('./config/routeLink') in each and every router?

Comment: @menaka nope, unless you make it [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) variable thru your whole application, ps: even its a bad practice to use global variables, will edit my answer.

Comment: gin chan :) , I dont wont to use a bad practice,i just didnt want to repeat require('./config/routeLink') again and again in each and every Router

Comment: lmao chan, anyway this routeLink is just a config file ? if yes, I hardly recommend to use them as environment variable and they will be available in your whole application, hint take a look at `dotenv` module

Comment: yes , just dont wanted to keep my route path static in every place , with this now i can change easy,if i needed to change a redirect path

Comment: yes this could work ,can you edit your answer to this so i can make it as the correct one